# Nginx prefix location config

Tags: nginx

How would I go about doing a rewrite in nginx vhost for a prefix to a domain?

ie: /var/www/site.com/public/ as root with /community in /public folder.

becomes: community.site.com in browser?

```
location /community {
    root /var/www/site.com/public/community/;
    rewrite "community."$document_root$uri.php;
}
```

I haven't used prefixes before and this is completely wrong. I can't find any tutorials on it either so I came here.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is called a subdomain, it's a separate server block and needs to be defined in the DNS server.

```
server {
  server_name community.example.com;
  root /var/www/site.com/public/community/;
  location / {
    # change this to match ur site/framework working technique.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
  }
}
```

This won't work unless you make sure that `host community.example.com` would return your server IP, and of course don't forget to restart/reload your nginx service.

Comment: you could say it's a totally different domain name, like instead of having `example1.com`, `example2.com`, you do `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com`